# How can I safely create a partition to an already bootable drive

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, startup, partition

I already asked this question on Apple's community forum, [right here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7590230), so I'll post the answer here if something comes up there first.

This is my problem :

I recently bought an external drive of 500Gb with the intent to use it to store large files that I use on my Mac and to use it as a bootable drive for Windows.
I followed [this](http://bleeptobleep.blogspot.ch/2013/02/mac-install-windows-7-or-8-on-external.html) tutorial to make the drive bootable on Windows 10, everything works well for that part.
Now I want to be able to partition the drive so that I can have **2 parts for Windows** (1 part that contains the infos for the boot, 1 that contains Windows) and **1 part that I can use on the Mac side to store files**. I thought that I could simple use the partition operation on the **Disk Utility app**, but the operation is *greyed out*. I found many answers on forums, but none of them is exactly what I'm looking for. Any idea how I can can achieve it ?

The actual state of the drive :

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE          IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk2
   1:                 DOS_FAT_32 WINBOOT                 209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:               Windows_NTFS BOOTCAMP                499.9 GB   disk2s2
```

Thanks in advance and have a good day !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after spending the afternoon looking how to solve this, I found that the easy way was to create a new partition from Windows' side in exFat format. And since the format exFat is modifiable on Mac, unlike NTFS, I can then erase it and then change the format to whichever I want.

Comment: Great! Please mark your question as solved then

Comment: Ah, forgot, my bad.